# Setting the seed value for an identity column in visual studio/entity framework w/SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql, entity-framework

Is it possible to override the seed value when creating a new table using the designer in 
visual studio?

I know it does not really matter from a programmatic point of view, but I don't like when ID's start at 1. I don't want to see customer ID of '1' or a sales order of 3 - I prefer them to all be the same length - i.e. 4 or 5 or 6 digits long, so depending on the estimate size of the data I always use 1,000, 10,000 or 100,000 as the starting seed value.

I know I can do it in SQL management studio, but even when I do set the seed to 1,000 or 10,000, if I refresh the EDMX from the database it reverts back to IDENTITY(1,1) and I don't want to have to do this for dozens of tables everytime I recreate the model. I can't find anything in the property window that would allow me to override this behavior.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Entity Designer Database Generation Power Pack](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/df3541c3-d833-4b65-b942-989e7ec74c87) will allow you to update a DB schema without recreating the DB from scratch.