# How to start Entity Framework Identity from 0

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

This is my configuration where my primary key column is `NetworkId` and it's `DatabaseGeneratedOption` is `Identity`.

```
public NetworkConfiguration() : base()
{
   this.HasKey(e => e.NetworkId);
   Property(e => e.NetworkId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
}
```

This value starts from 1 always can I make it to start with 0?

Comment: Check out [EF Code First - how to set identity seed?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5974554/1931491), [How do I set Identity seed on an ID column using Entity Framework 4 code first with SQL Compact 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11732102/1931491), [Setting the seed value for an identity column in visual studio/entity framework w/SQL Server 2008R2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4051459/1931491)

Answer (score 0):

In MVC 3 and EF 4.1 you could try something like this:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT ('NetworkConfiguration', RESEED, 0)");
```

followed by the method that populates your table with the rest of the values

```
SeedNetworkConfiguration();
```

Answer (score -3):

Database ids will always start at 1. Out of interest, why would you want an id to be 0?

Comment: We need to start it from 0, because our project entities start from 0

Comment: Ok - to be honest, I don't know if you can start it at zero or not, but having a row in the database with an identifier of 0 to me sounds like a bad idea.